# Exponential functions with negative base

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

Consider the function $f(x) = (-2)^x$, $x$ belongs to irrationals. For which $x$ does $f(x)$ belong to the reals.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck! Here is a guide to write Mathjax expressions: 
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: its actually simple, you are given a function and a domain for that function. Im trying to find for which inputs are the outputs of the function real numbers. sorry for the confusion i guess

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite

> $$
> f(x) = (-2)^x = 2^x \mathbf{i}^{2x}
> = 2^x \Big( \cos(\pi x) + \mathbf{i} \sin(\pi x ) \Big).
> $$

So real for

> $$
> \sin(\pi x) = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x \in \mathbb{Z}.
> $$

General base

> $$
> f(x) = (-b)^x =b^x (-1)^x = b^x \mathbf{i}^{2x}
> = b^x \Big( \cos(\pi x) + \mathbf{i} \sin(\pi x ) \Big).
> $$

So real for

> $$
> \sin(\pi x) = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x \in \mathbb{Z}.
> $$

Comment: What is k? Do you mean x?