# Solving inequalities containing exponential functions, eg, $\frac{(x^2-4)3x}{2^{x-2}(8x+16)}\leq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I know solving inequalities using table method ,i.e , finding each values of variable that makes it zero , and writing the root  a line and change the sign when you have odd root. It is classical high school method. However , i encounter with different question style such that it contains exponential function. However , i do not know how to solve them when exponential functions involved in , so i want to learn the techniques for them. For example , how can i solve :

- $$\frac{(x^2-4)3x}{2^{x-2}(8x+16)}\leq 0$$

What is the role of exponential function , should i include $(x-2)=0 \rightarrow 2$ or the sign of "x" , it is positive.

**NOTE** I am open to any other source to read and improve myself about it

Comment: Any power of 2 is always positive, so you can ignore it.

Comment: @insipidintegrator what if it were $(-2)^{x-2}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392545/exponential-functions-with-negative-base @ilikemath

Answer (score 1):

it's equivalent to  $x(x-2) \leq 0,$  therefore the set of solutions is $[0,2].$

Answer (score 0):

Simply note that $2^{x-2}>0 \space\forall \space x \in \mathbb R$. The inequality now reduces to $$\frac{3x(x^2-4)}{8x+16}\le0$$
which is something you mentioned as being comfortable with.